# Testing the wso2 Api Manager using cURL

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2 AM 1.10.0 and trying to test the application deployed on wso2. I am following these steps.

**1. Login**

---

```
curl -k -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

return `{"error" : false}`

**2. Generate application key**

---

```
curl -k -X POST -b cookies http://localhost/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d 'action=generateApplicationKey&application=DefaultApplication&keytype=sandbox&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains=ALL&validityTime=360000' --header "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

Nothing return. Also no error message in any log files.

Sole purpose of above-mentioned steps is to acquire access key for my application.

```
curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "**Authorization: Bearer ed04181739cf3cfd6791d11534f63cbd**" "url"
```

I need help about how to test myapi.

---

EDIT(from comment/answer by OP):

wso2carbon.log shows

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-17 16:56:04,040] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} - Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} java.lang.NullPointerException at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2607) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:380) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126) at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430) at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269) at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_9(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:32) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:240) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394) at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag) at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567) at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-17 16:56:04,042] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag} - org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag}
```

---

Now I am having the following exception which indicates duplicate record exception. Although I have already generated the access key and wants to regenerate it.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-17 20:59:07,580] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2651)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:380)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_9(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:240)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occured when updating the status of the Application creation process
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2626)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while creating an Application Registration Entry for Application : DefaultApplication
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.handleException(ApiMgtDAO.java:7259)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.createApplicationRegistrationEntry(ApiMgtDAO.java:330)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_F9 ON PUBLIC.AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION(SUBSCRIBER_ID, APP_ID, TOKEN_TYPE)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO  AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION (SUBSCRIBER_ID,WF_REF,APP_ID,TOKEN_TYPE,ALLOWED_DOMAINS,VALIDITY_PERIOD,TOKEN_SCOPE,INPUTS)   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23001-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:157)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtree.find(PageBtree.java:121)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeLeaf.addRow(PageBtreeLeaf.java:138)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeLeaf.addRowTry(PageBtreeLeaf.java:93)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.addRow(PageBtreeIndex.java:90)
        at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.add(PageBtreeIndex.java:81)
        at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:116)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:120)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:82)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:70)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:199)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.createApplicationRegistrationEntry(ApiMgtDAO.java:311)
        ... 69 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-17 20:59:07,583] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag} -  org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using new  [rest api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/). One you are using is deprecated

Comment: Chamila I have to write a script to verify the already configured product. Product is also configured using shell script.

Comment: Using Rest Api is good, however, guide me how to generate **"Authorization: Bearer aa0ddec1ac656744234477f20fafcb0d"** using curl.

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/#guide contains the steps to create and get the token to use with the rest api. 'access_token' coming from the last step is the token

Comment: Thanks @Chamila Adhikarinayake,  what will be in **callbackUrl** and **clientName**. How to get these values?

Comment: If you are using password grant type or client credential grant type, then this url is not needed (sample token is generated using password grant type in the next command) . if u are interested u can read the spec :D (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) . client name is the name of the oauth2 application. you can put what ever u like. you only need client id and client secret once the oauth2 application is created

Comment: I have deployed my application having following properties.
**"providerName": "admin", "apiName": "MYAPI", "version": "1.0.0"**.

    curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic adadaasd4545as" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.9/register
**{
    "callbackUrl": "",
    "clientName": "MYAPI",
    "tokenScope": "Sandbox",
    "owner": "admin",
    "grantType": "password refresh_token",
    "saasApp": true
    }**

It gives error : {"description":"Unauthenticated request","moreInfo":"","code":401,"message":"","error":[]}

Comment: Carbon.log    ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  Password cannot be null/empty

Comment: token in  Basic adadaasd4545as in your request should be base64 encoded username:password

Comment: This time i used it like so..
1. eString=$(echo -n admin:password | base64)
2. curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic $eString" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.9/register
3. { "callbackUrl": "", "clientName": "MYAPI", "tokenScope": "Sandbox", "owner": "admin", "grantType": "password refresh_token", "saasApp": true }
It gives correct json first time only, next time it gives Error occurred while registering client. How to get values after registration.
Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two mistakes here.

1. If you want to generate the token, you need to login to store, not publisher and get the cookies.

   ```
   curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
   ```
2. The URL you have used to generate the toekn don't have port, so I guess, the request sent to default port 80, hence you don't get any response.

   ```
   curl -k -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d 'action=generateApplicationKey&application=DefaultApplication&keytype=SANDBOX&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains=ALL&validityTime=360000' --header "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
   ```

Please note that, keytype should be either `SANDBOX` or `PRODUCTION`, case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake. Now it gives following error. "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey"

Comment: @K.Khalid, Do you have any exception trace in API Manager logs?

Comment: @K.Khalid, I have updated the answer, keytype should be either SANDBOX or PRODUCTION, case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have run it and this time it gives exception which i have edited in my post.